# What are the feats of strength in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Like the title says - what are the known feats of strength in the game?

Comment: Not confirmed, just a thought: Killing Diablo in Hardcore Inferno

Comment: There's a [regular achievement for that](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/the-prime-evil-inferno); I doubt they'd double it up

Comment: Should have done my homework, well nevertheless +1 since I'm definitely interested in further FoS discoveries

Comment: What exactly makes a "feat of strength" different from a regular achievement?

Comment: There's no hard line, but feats of strength are often exclusive (like the collector's edition), very difficult to obtain, or are categorized that way so that they don't provide extra hints to players

Comment: Should be wikied

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a list of data-mined feats of strength thus far: http://d3db.com/achievement/?c=5505067#1-1-0

They fall into several categories:

- "One of the Chosen" - Participated in the Diablo 3 closed beta
- Participated in the web promotion for each class (earning the sigils by creating banners)
- "Discriminating Taste" - Bought the Collector's Edition
- "In the Land of Killer Unicorns" - Get to the [secret non-cow level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii) for ideas
- "Kill the unburied Jay Wilson" - Kill a monster named after D3's Game Director, in a special [secret dungeon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68408/the-foul-depths-of-the-quality-well/68412)

Comment: Do you know if people who got into the web promotion got their FoS already?

Comment: Kill the unburied Jay Wilson is by completing the special easteregg dungeon ["Development Hell".](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68412/336)

Comment: @VincentSavard As of yesterday, I still did not get the FoS from the web promotion.

Answer (score 3):

"One of the Chosen" is the only Feat of Strength that has been discovered so far, to my knowledge. It is the Feat of Strength given to players that were in the closed beta.

Comment: Collectors edition gives another one as well; (I can't log in to tell you the name...)

Comment: Digging the internet for that one, not having much luck so far finding it anywhere, lol.

Comment: Aha - "Discriminating Taste" is the name of it

Answer (score 3):

I also did all five class web promotions during the pre-release of the game.  Blizzard took their while to grant these but they're all in my account now.

They're named:

- "Brushed up on the Barb" for the barbarian
- "Wise to the Wizard"
- "Delved into the Demon Hunter"
- "Witch Doctor discovered"
- "Mindful of the Monk"

All were credited on the 28th of June (at least for me)

Answer (score 1):

"Kill the unburied Jay Wilson" got this one, and its title is "Smash! Jay, smash!"

Its a secret level in one of the crypts, when doing the black kings crown in the cemetary.
when you enter the crypt changes its name to "developers hell" and all the mobs are, well, developers... Zombies with names of people working on D3... And the boss is none other than Jay Wilson!

Comment: "When you enter the crypt changes its name to 'developers hell'" =>
It was not the case for me. Its name was "Developpers Hell" before I entered.

Answer (score 1):

In the land of Killer Unicorns is another feat of strength got it on the 18th

Comment: Due to entering the secret dungeon?

Comment: yes, it took me 2 days to farm the mats and 350k gold

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten 3 so far.

D3 Collector's Edition

Killing the Unburied Jay Wilson in Developer Hell (random 4th dungeon at the crypts in Nightmare or higher)

Finding Whimseyshire (secret unicorn/rainbow level)

As far as the exclusive sigils go, I've not seen anything from Blizzard yet on these. I did all 5, have the emails as proof and time stamps but do not have them on my account.