# Who killed Iron Wolf Bowden?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Act 2, in the North East corner, I keep finding the corpse of Iron Wolf Bowden.  I'm not certain, but I think he may have been there every single time, and I know that when I do find him, he's always in the same spot.

Is there something special about this corpse?  Who is (or rather, was) Bowden?  Are there any quests or special events linked to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no other reference to this person in the dialog or other assets in the game that I can find, so I don't think there's an "in-universe" explanation as to who this person is.

However, [Nathan Bowden](http://www.diablowiki.net/Nathan_Bowden) is one of the artists for the game, so it's highly likely that this is an easter egg left by the development team.  Nate is also [one of the zombies](http://d3db.com/npc/i/nate-bowden) you can fight in [Development Hell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67860/where-is-development-hell-and-the-unburied-jay-wilson).