# The foul depths of the Quality Well

Tags: diablo-iii

After reading about Development Hell and the unburied Jay Wilson, I happened to stumble upon the Quality Well (on Nightmare) whilst clearing out Old Tristram. Upon my decent into the dark murkiness of the well, I found it populated by all manner of foul, lurking beasts: Blizzard QA zombies.

[image]

Is there any other purpose behind the Quality Well, other than to show off the undead QA team?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope - just a secret joke dungeon. Rumor has it that if you're particularly unfortunate, you might stumble across [Development Hell](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snC4LhhOGis), as well.. (I know you mentioned it, but seriously. *Development Hell*. It deserves a second mention.)

Oh, and you might also find Bashiok lurking around the Oasis in Act 2. If you've got Rakanishu's Blade, he's even worth an achievement.

Comment: Zarhym's in the game too. I found him somewhere in Act I on my first playthrough.

Comment: Zarhym seems to be one of the random names for Rares, I've seen him around the place a few times in my first playthrough on Normal.