# How can I find the hidden level?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reach the secret level in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii)

I was wondering, if there was a Cow-level-kind in Diablo3 and I found this ["In the Land of Killer Unicorns"](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/in-the-land-of-killer-unicorns), but none of the current comments says anything of How could I get it, or Find the hidden level.

How could I find the hidden level?