# Will a higher level Staff of Herding open the lower difficulty Whimsyshire?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I know that there are multiple levels of the Staff of Herding, and they get significantly more expensive as you go up in difficulties.  I play with a lot of people who have varying amounts of time to play, and will be at vastly different levels.  I'd like to be able to go into the unicorn level with anyone, no matter what level they are.

Will I need to get a staff for each level if I want to be able to enter Whimsyshire on multiple difficulties, or will an Inferno Staff open all the lower level portals?

Comment: I would doubt it since the only cost of making a higher difficulty staff is the staff from the previous difficulty.

Comment: Yeah, but higher level staff recipes require a ton of gold, not to mention having to farm all the individual items again.  Just hoping I can avoid that :)

Comment: i hoped to find answer tonight, but servers went out again, need a little more gold to make NM mode one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible to open lower difficulties of Wimsyshire with a higher level staff.
In this video I open the Normal difficulty using Nightmarish Staff of Herding:

This makes us udderly pleased.

Comment: I was going to post that I see you provided a video, that is good.  But you already milked that pun dry...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't provide a video source, but YES a higher difficulty Staff of Herding will also work for lower difficulties.

Comment: This answer is not much help, unless you can confirm that _you yourself_ have done this, or someone in a game with you has.

Comment: @Snailer Agreed.  ItsColby, if you've done it yourself, or been in a party that has, edit your answer to say so, and I'll gladly accept it.