# Does Whimsyshire have a boss?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does [Whimsyshire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii) (the secret level) have a boss(a [Super Unique Monster](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Unique_Monsters)) like the Secret Cow level in Diablo 2 has the Cow King?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least 2, Creampuff and Nightmarty.  Apparently they have a chance to drop a rainbow flavored unique as well.  Skip to 3:25 for his mention of them.