# Can I enter Whimsyshire if I follow someone in my party with the Staff of Herding?

Tags: diablo-iii

I wanted to know, if everybody in my group can access Whimsyshire in Diablo 3, when only I have the staff of herding? Or does everybody need to have this staff?

Comment: I believe that the secret cow level equivalent is called Whimsyshire. I'm not sure that there are any cows there, though.

Comment: There is no cow level.  However... 

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii

Duplicate

Comment: Hi, and thanks. I am aware of that. Sorry, should have said "Whimsyshire".  What I wanted to ask is: Do my friends need the staff too? Or do they need to make their own? I know how to make that staff ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The staff is only required to open the way to Whimsyshire. After it is accessible, anyone in the game can enter.