# Is the Secret Level worth farming for equipment?

Tags: diablo-iii

Now that a [secret level is confirmed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66096/13845), is it as good as the old Secret Cow Level in Diablo II in terms of drops? Does the heavy cost involved in getting there (150,000+ gold) make it worth (equipment wise) to spend the time and money to gain access to the level?

Comment: There's [a legendary sword](http://d3db.com/item/i/spectrum) made of rainbows, unicorn smiles, shooting stars, and teddy bear giggles.

Answer (score 1):

It is a money sink and nothing else. I for some reason got tons of gold during Act II on normal. I played it normally and didn't get Achievements so did it again just to get them and then my friend got there so I decided to play with him so he could catch up with me so I got even more. By the end I just decided to buy the items since I even got the pattern for it. I am close to hitting 1 million gold Achievement even though I am only in Act II on Nightmare now.