# What does Wirt's Bell do?

Tags: diablo-iii

I came across a vendor, `Squirt The Peddler`, in act II that sells: **Wirt's Bell** for **100,000** Gold.  What does that bell do and is it worth it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used for [reaching the secret level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii) (along with a bunch of other items and crafting which actually costs more money). Whether spending that much to reach it is "worth it" is entirely up to you :)

Comment: :O .............yes please!

Answer (score 10):

You need:

- that item,
- 50,000 G,
- the Black Mushrooms, found in Cathedral
- Liquid Rainbow, found in the Mysterious Cave, located in Dahlgur Oasis
- Gibbering Gem Stone, found in Caves of Frost lvl 2 - dropped by Chitara random purple mob
- Blacksmith plans for staff of hurting (dropped from Izual)
- Leoric's Shin Bone (found in Leoric Manner by the fireplace randomly)

When you have all that, go to the blacksmith and ask him to build it (50,000 G); after you assemble it go to the cow bones (Act I) and enter the level called Whimseyshire. It was awesome and totally worth it.

Be warned! You should be at least level 30 before trying to enter this realm. (Normal mode; I dunno about the upper levels.)

Comment: I cant find the mysterious cave ? Are you sure its in that area?

Comment: @shaun The cave is a random spawn, not always there. And to make it even better, Chitara is a random spawn as well, AND the drop chance of the item is less then 100%. Most definitely the most annoying of the items to farm.

Comment: The staff is called "staff of herding" btw ;) not "hurting". And the level of the mobs in Wimsyshire is roughly the same as the mobs in late act III / early act IV of the corresponding difficulty. Also note that in order to access the higher difficulties you need a new plan for the staff of herding (drops from Izual in the corresponding difficulty) which always costs the previous staff plus 100k (or maybe 50, not sure). So in order to enter infernal Wimsyshire, you need to get the plans from Izual in all four difficulty levels. You can still enter lower difficulty levels with the higher staves