# Is there any way to dial back the gore in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it possible to dial back the gore in diablo 3? My fiancee loves the gameplay but she can't handle the squishy aspects.

Comment: Note on "squishy", if you've not run over one of the random animals that are crawling around with your sound on, then do so now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a "gore" setting, per se, as this is kind of the art/style of the game.  (Well, [most of it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii) anyway...)

However, I find that playing with the graphics settings turned all the way down makes everything look a lot less...  visceral.  The slightly off colors and the low-res textures make the art look more like a B-grade horror movie than anything at all realistic.  However, the cutscenes are the same quality regardless, so be ready to skip them if they get a bit too disgusting.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://blues.incgamers.com/Posts/10/1/40/819/140026/reduced-gore-option) from a Blizzard employee, there is not a 'reduced gore' option, and there are no plans to add one.

> We don't currently have any plans to provide reduced gore options. The game is rated M for Mature, which is a 17+ rating, and we encourage parents to remain aware of game ratings, the content in the game that led to that rating, and keep them in mind when choosing which games are appropriate for their family.

<strike>Please note that these are not the official Blizzard forums, so it's possible that the person is not who they say they are.</strike>

Edit: Thanks to Ashel for pointing out that the post is actually from a Blizzard employee.

Comment: That post *is* from the official Blizzard forums, actually - http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3797680338?page=3#44 - blues.incgamers.com is just a service for tracking the posts of Blizzard employees, or 'blues', so named after their text color.