# How do I get higher difficulty Plan: Staff of Herding?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I have made Staff of Herding and I wanted to get the plans for the Nightmarish version, but after killing Izual a couple of times on Nightmare and getting Plan: Staff of Herding two times I don't think that is where I get, but where do I then get it?

Comment: What about the rest of the items? Do I need to farm them at the difficulty that I want?

Comment: @MichelAyres No you just need to farm them to make the first Staff of Herding, the rest you just need to buy the plans, teach Haedrig them and upgrade the staff.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get the Nightmarish, Hellish or Infernal version of Plan: Staff of Herding you will need to go to the last part of Act IV (Prime Evil) on the difficulty you desire and then talk to **Gorell the Quartermaster** who is standing next to the healer, he will sell it to you:

- 20,000 for Plans: Nightmarish Staff of Herding
- 50,000 for Plans: Hellish Staff of Herding
- 100,000 for Plans: Infernal Staff of Herding

Upgrading the staff at the blacksmith costs:

- 200,000 for Nightmarish Staff of Herding
- 500,000 for Hellish Staff of Herding
- 1,000,000 for Infernal Staff of Herding

[image: old Picture]
Picture is from before the price change.

Comment: It seems this has been changed. I was trying to buy the Nightmarish recipe, and Gorell wanted 20K gold for it.

Comment: îs it possible to skip to infernal or do i need to buy+craft each step?

Comment: @wandang You have to buy and craft each step since the recipe will require the previous staff as an ingredient.