# How do you upgrade the Staff of Herding?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get higher difficulty Plan: Staff of Herding?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68220/how-do-i-get-higher-difficulty-plan-staff-of-herding)

I've recently collected all of the parts for the Staff of Herding to enter Whimsyshire. However, the normal difficulty drops are a bit lacking, how can I upgrade the staff to gain access to better items?

Comment: Are you asking how to upgrade to the different difficulty levels of the staff? Or are you wondering if there is a formula to give it magic find?

Comment: how to upgrade the levels of the staff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get better items is to access the secret level in higher difficulties - for that you have to upgrade your staff.

Important to say that you have to start a quest where Izual is already dead on that particular difficulty for the merchant to offer the plans.

- [Nightmarish Staff of Herding](http://www.diablowiki.net/Nightmarish_Staff_of_Herding)
- [Hellish Staff of Herding](http://www.diablowiki.com/Hellish_Staff_of_Herding)
- [Infernal Staff of Herding](http://www.diablowiki.com/Infernal_Staff_of_Herding)