# What are the locations of the traveling merchants for the Market Research achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The "Market Research" achievement requires that you meet the following traveling merchants:

> - Wandering Tinker
> - Rodger the Alchemist
> - Vendel the Armorsmith
> - Adenath the Curio Vendor
> - Kyr the Weaponsmith
> - Zaven the Alchemist
> - Larra
> - Halmin the Alchemist

Where are these merchants located?  Can they be found in an exact location, or do they roam a whole zone (or worse yet, are there locations totally random)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I waited a week before posting in case Ashel ever did find Halmin, but since they didn't, here's the answer with guides, including Halmin's location. I also contributed to Ashel's answer too, but that was when I didn't expect to find Halmin like a day later.

The locations of many of the wandering merchants appear randomly and for some of them, the merchants also appear randomly within those locations and so it will likely take several tries for each in order to get them.

### Wandering Tinker

**Wandering Tinker is always found at the Tinker's Hovel that is randomly at the Sheltered Cottage that is always to the north of the Fields of Misery in Act I.** The nearest waypoint is Fields of Misery. Port in and run north. There's a lore book just outside the Tinker's Hovel.

[image: Tinker's Hovel]

### Rodger the Alchemist

**Rodger the Alchemist is randomly found across the bridge of the Wortham Bluffs during the quest Trailing the Coven in Act I.** Despite nearly 100 attempts, I have never seen him appear except during this quest. The nearest waypoint is the Wortham Chapel Cellar. Port in and run until you get to the other side of the bridge.

[image: Rodger the Alchemist]

### Vendel the Armorsmith

**Vendel the Armorsmith is randomly found in The Watch Tower Level 2 which is randomly found on the west edge of Southern Highlands in Act I.** The nearest waypoint is Northern Highlands. Port in and run west, then search north and south to get your relative position and see if you find The Watch Tower - Dash through Level 1 and see if Vendel appears once you enter Level 2. Complete his quest to get a lore book and access to his shop. Ashel mentions this dungeon also being in Act III, but I have never seen it there.

- As of patch 1.05 it's the southern Highlands

[image: The Watch Tower]

### Adenath the Curio Vendor

**Adenath the Curio Vendor is always found at the House of Curios that is randomly found at one of four locations in the Fields of Misery.** It can be at any of the 3 landmarks in the picture (either dungeon or the waypoint), or at a location far north and slightly east of the northern-most dungeon (in this picture). There's a lore book inside the House of Curios.

[image: House of Curios]

### Kyr the Weaponsmith

**Kyr the Weaponsmith is randomly found in the Highlands Passage just outside of the exit from Halls of Agony Level 2 in Act I.** The nearest waypoint is Halls of Agony Level 2. Port in and run generally south-east until you exit Halls of Agony Level 2. Complete his quest to gain access to his shop.

[image: Kyr the Weaponsmith]

### Zaven the Alchemist

**Zaven the Alchemist is randomly found in one of the southern tips of Dahlgur Oasis by the entrance to The Mysterious Cave in Act II.** I believe I have found him at either of these tips but I definitely found him on the eastern one this time. The nearest waypoints are Path to the Oasis and Dahlgur Oasis. Port in, run south until you hit one tip and then continue towards the other. If you visit both waypoints, it makes it easier to get your bearings. Save him from some ghosts in order to gain access to his shop and the Mysterious Cave (where one of the components of [The Staff of Herding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67096/23580) can be found).

[image: Mysterious Cave]

### Larra

**Larra is found in a randomly occurring Deserted Cellar that is randomly in Black Canyon Mines in Act II.** The deserted cellar can spawn to the north or to the south. ***I have never found Larra at any of the southern deserted cellars.*** Also, I believe it is unlikely that the Blood Cellar and Deserted Cellar both spawn. Having a deserted cellar spawn and having it be the one with Larra are both random. The nearest waypoint is Black Canyon Mines. Port in an run north-west. The correct cellar will have a hovel named Larra at the back and your character will coax Larra into leaving the hovel and doing business with you. You will also get a lore book.

[image: Deserted Cellar]

### Halmin the Alchemist

**Halmin the Alchemist is randomly found in The Foundry Level 1 which is randomly in The Battlefields in Act III.** The nearest waypoint is The Bridge of Korsikk. Port in, run south and check if you see a big fort in the middle of The Battlefields with no access from the back, then run around the front to see if it's The Foundry. You will need to kill some enemies in a room with a fireplace which I found both times in the north-east part of the map and then Helmin will crawl out from under a bed and give you access to his shop. If you find a room with a fireplace and Halmin's not there, you may want to re-instance and try again.

[image: The Foundry Level 1]

Comment: Wow, that was awesome.  I don't normally move checks, but in this case I think it's warranted.

Comment: I would have too - it's considerably more in-depth, and all personally researched and verified.

Comment: the Wandering Tinker isn't allways there

Comment: @Hurda You've found Tinker's Hovel and not had Wandering Tinker inside?

Comment: You sometimes can't enter, in that instance a lot of frogs is in front i think. (and possibly get different Journal)

Comment: @Hurda Then it's not Tinker's Hovel. As I said, "Wandering Tinker is always found at ***the Tinker's Hovel that is randomly at the Sheltered Cottage*** that is always to the north of the Fields of Misery in Act I." The Sheltered Cottage is the sub-area in Fields of Misery and it is always there. Whether Tinker's Hovel or the Cottage with all the bodies or that journal appear there are random, hence "the Tinker's Hovel that is ***randomly*** at the Sheltered Cottage."

Comment: @skovacs1 ah, so now I see

Comment: Just for the record, I did find the Foundry without having Halmin inside.

Comment: Want to upvote, but lack of freehand circles....  :) +1 anyway!

Comment: @skovacs1 thanks.  I cleared the whole foundry level 1 about twelve times before having one with Halmin in it before finally getting one where he spawned.   One thing to note is that he appears in a room with a fireplace (but he is not always in that room).   I also have never seen two fireplace rooms in the foundry, so it might be safe to quit looking after you find the fireplace.

Comment: Since Halmin is a tough one, two tips that I found necessary to get him: 1) Foundry seems to spawn well when you are doing "Machines of War" and running out of the Keep.  If you run back from the Bridge of Korsik instead, it seems to always spawns the Battlefields one for me (prolly 50+ attempts).  Secondly, you can see in pictures on d3db like [here](http://d3db.com/static/uploads/original/27085d0a592e1603b52f0f7e7d62d864.jpg) that Halmin always seems to spawn in a room north of a "W" shape on the map.  The "W" is a void, from a staircase I believe.  He spawned there for me as well.

Answer (score 9):

I've got bad news - they're semi-random. Each of them is linked to a particular zone event -

- the Wandering Tinker spawns in the Sheltered Cottage, a sub-area of the Fields of Misery in Act I.
- Rodger the Alchemist can spawn after leaving Wortham in Act I and crossing the stony bridge.
- Vendel the Armorsmith spawns on the second level of the Watch Tower, a sub-zone on the bridge in Act III. He also has a chance to spawn in the Watch Tower in the Northern Highlands in Act I, selling to you after the completion of an event, the Scabbard of Talic the Defender.
- Adenath the Curio Vendor also spawns in the Fields of Misery in a sub-area called the House of Curios. You'll also find a lore item here, Adenath's Jottings.
- Kyr the Weaponsmith has a chance of spawning on the Highlands Passage after leaving level 2 of the Halls of Agony in Act I. He'll ask you to help him out, do so and he'll sell to you.
- Zaven the Alchemist spawns in the Dahlgur Oasis in Act II, along the southern side of the zone, being attacked by ghosts. Help him out and he'll sell to you, as well as open up the Mysterious Cave (where you can find - also randomly - a Mysterious Chest with one of the pieces for the Staff of Herding.)
- Larra spawns in a Deserted Cellar in the Black Canyon Mines in Act II. She'll be hiding in a tent - convince her to come out and she'll sell to you.
- Halmin the Alchemist's location is currently unknown to me! I'll edit this post if/when it's discovered.

Thanks again to Beofett and skovacs1 for providing additional information on the locations of Vendel and Larra.

Comment: I found the Watch Tower on the bridge, after the catapults and trebuchet.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks much - I couldn't remember exactly where it was, as that whole area has quite a few sub-zones.

Comment: Larra can be found in a Deserted Cellar in Black Canyon Mines in Act II. She's hiding in a tent inside the cellar and you coax her out. Then she'll sell you her wares. Vendel the Armorsmith also rarely spawns in the Watch Tower in Northern Highlands in Act I and has the event Scabbard of Talic the Defender (and yields the associated People Lore book as well) after whose completion, you may buy his wares.

Answer (score 1):

Halmin the Alchemist *seems* to spawn only when you get this Foundry:

[image]

Just remember to kill all the enemies in his room first.

He always spawns in that same surrounding area (in the small room, above the "square area" that encloses a 'w'-like path. However, this "surrounding area" can differ slightly in position in the Foundry.

Answer (score 0):

Farming Zaven the Alchemist I found a little trick using the fact that the southwestern waypoint always spawns in the same spot.  If you take it and visit the southern spawn area and Zaven isn't there, just TP back to town, take the other waypoint, open the map and drag the SW waypoint onto your health globe, then mark the second spawn point on your monitor with a little piece of tape.  That way you'll find it exactly every time and won't get lost.

Any little bit helps with these guys, I think I had to try about 70 times before I found him (and the chest).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So for Halmin, it doesnt have to be in that exact instance of the Foundry lvl 1.

After an hour or so (and thats even with dismissing a couple foundries because they weren't the layout as suggested above) I found him.

So basically, just look for that room with a fireplace above that "surrounding area" in all foundries :)

Comment: I have a screenshot of where is was for me but since im a newbie it wont let me post.