# Where to find the Old Keepsake Box?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The Old Keepsake Box contains 8 of the journals needed by Act 1 achievements "A Quick Study" and "Historian of Tristram". Based on the answer at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/70084/26911, 
it can be found randomly in Old Tristram or The Old Ruins. Is there a quick way to locate the box?

List of Journals:

- Cain's Old Journal, Part 1
- Cain's Old Journal, Part 2
- Gillian's Diary, Part 1
- Gillian's Diary, Part 2
- Lost Journal
- Old Diary
- Despina's Journal
- Old Tristram Journal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quickest way is to start the quest "Legacy Of Cain" and use the waypoint to The Old Ruins. Look for the Old Keepsake Box at the locations marked by red X. Once found or not(it could have spawned at the The Old Tristram Road), leave the game and resume. Repeat until all 6 journals are found.

[image: The Old Ruins]

**Update:** From further testing, the box appears most often in those 2 locations I've marked. If not found, try looking at the other locations mentioned in Rill's answer.

Comment: Much faster to switch to the beginning of the "Legacy of Cain" quest: just use the Old Ruins waypoint, check the locations you've marked (and a third location, a decaying house in the north of the old town), then teleport back to town and repeat.

Comment: Does the difficulty level matter?

Comment: @Bora Difficulty level doesn't matter. Just do it on Normal is fine.

Comment: @ericp Thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

I have updated the map with the locations I have found the box in. 
[image: Old keepsake box]

Good Luck.

Comment: I tried about 20 times. Managed to find the box in all locations except the 2 leftmost ones.

Comment: It just spawned for me right by the waypoint.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you go on the road from New Tristram onto the Old Tristram Road and continue onto the Old Ruin because you can actually find TWO Old Keepsake Boxes. Also, you can run into dungeons that you haven't done before too as they renew when you restart the game and run it again.