# Where to find the wandering tinker's diary?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the Act 1 lore books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70083/where-are-the-act-1-lore-books)

For the quick study achievement you need to read the Wandering tinker's diary, but I have been unable to find it anywhere. Any tips appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Dup: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70083/where-are-the-act-1-lore-books

Comment: To search for question under a specific tag use the square brackets, e.g. [diablo-3] wandering tinker's diary