# Where is the Gravedigger's Log in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

In order to complete the Historian of Tristram achievement I'm trying to find the "Gravedigger's Log" world lore book in Act I.
Can someone give me some pointers on where to find it?

Comment: Yep, you're right. I couldn't find that question when searching for  variations of "Gravedigger's Log".

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found a very good answer in the [Where are the Act 1 lore books](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70083/where-are-the-act-1-lore-books) question suggested by @spartacus.

One thing to note, I respawned quite a number of times but couldn't get the Gravedigger's Skeleton to drop the book. I eventually gave up and switched to another, lower level, character and the book dropped first time.