# What is the best vendor for jewelry?

Tags: diablo-iii

I thought I might get lucky with some vendor for jewelry, as I did not find any way to craft rings and amulets.

I tried Litton the Fence in Act IV Inferno, but basically he sells shitty items. Mostly blue items at level 55 or less.

What is the vendor with he best jewelry in the game and what kind of items does he sell (level, number of attributes etc.)?

Is it actually possible to buy rare level 59 or 60 jewelry?

Comment: Try looking for the random spawning merchants outside the town. Sometimes they have some decent items.

Comment: Vendors won't have good stuff for jewelry or anything else, you can make a habit of checking them on the off-chance of perfect MF/GF stat to give to follower - but I suggest using AH for all your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Novarg says random merchant outside of town always have 1 rare item to sell.
But....seriously....if you want good jewelry use Auction House has i don't see the chance of seeing a rare amulet or ring from a random vendor. That makes a low chances.

EDIT : To answer your comment i will redirect you [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68470/what-are-the-locations-of-the-traveling-merchants-for-the-market-research-achiev) there's screenshot of every merchant in the game and their spawns should be good enough :)

EDIT 2 : Since patch 1.07 you may craft rare amulets at the Jeweler. You may find more info [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/amulet/#type=crafted)

Comment: Could you list where I can find them?

Comment: It's listed in the answer in the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for decent jewellery is the auction house, hands down.  Yes you will pay a lot more, but by Act IV in Inferno you should have some sort of budget.

That aside, yes, the standard merchants can occasionally have rare items, or you can try to find the random vendors whose locations [are stated here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68470/10260).

Frankly the time you'll invest in attempting this will be far more than if you invest your time in farming and trade for what you want.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are correct that vendors are bad sources for good amulets and rings while the auction house is better (you pay more but get better items).  For the self-found, it's probably more reliable to farm rings and amulets by looting monsters.  Since those answers were posted, [patch 1.07](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/8608455/patch-107-now-live-2-12-2013) was released, which include new recipes for [amulet crafting](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/amulet/#type=crafted).  The current four recipes make account bound items with high item levels (63).