# What is the optimal way to grind the  Black Mushroom?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am only missing the Black Mushroom to have all the ingredients for the "Staff of herding". So I have to try and get it. The problem is it is unclear where it drops. So sources say you find it in Level 1,2 and 4 of the Cathedral in Act I. There are also some pictures of people finding the Black Mushroom outside. What is the optimal way of going about getting this ingredient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to find Black Mushrooms is (as others have said) the Cathedral Level 1.

The Cathedral is randomly generated, so you'll want to explore Level 1 fully, and if you don't find it, **leave the game** and return.  The Cathedral will regenerate, and you'll have another opportunity to find the mushroom.

If you've passed this area already, the best story checkpoint for this is "Act 1: Part 4 - Reign of the Skeleton King."  You'll start in town, so use the waypoint in town to take you to the Cathedral Garden.  Walk southwest, through the gate, and around to the front of the Cathedral.  Open the door, and descend through the hole in the floor to get to Cathedral Level 1.

Arrowmaster also suggests starting with the quest "The Legacy of Cain," with the stage "Explore Cellar" - if you play through this quest to the checkpoint at the Cathedral, you'll shave a bit of time leaving and re-entering the game.

Comment: For farming a location over and over its better to start on the quest that sends you there and get a checkpoint. If you do that then every time you leave and resume the game you will start at the beginning of Cath1 (or the end if you found the exit, but I just stayed away if I saw the blip on the minimap).

Comment: @Arrowmaster, for most of them, I'd agree, but this one the search area is relatively large (probably 5 minutes or so to clear) versus  the 10-15 seconds it takes to take the waypoint and walk to the Cathedral entrance.  If you know what quest milestone is closest to a checkpoint here, I'll add that to the answer, though.

Comment: The closest quest would be The Legacy of Cain, Explore Cellar.

Comment: It's also important to note that the mushrooms always spawn in th same _style_ room. That is, the room always has the same shape on the minimap. So, if you find that room quickly, you can just re-join without scouring the rest of the Cathedral. A picture can be found here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-whimsyshire-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii

Answer (score 5):

Since it was driving me mad that I didn't know what I was looking for (visually, that is), I took this screenshot of the black mushroom patch when I finally found it. Hope it helps:

[image]

I can also confirm that your character does not comment on the patch until clicking it.

Comment: It's always that room and seems to be usually at the bottom of the map -- from what I have seen.

Comment: While the gesture is really appreciated, that's an awful screenshot. Lol

Answer (score 3):

It has several spawn points throughout Act I, but the most likely spawn point seems to be in Cathedral Level 1. It can spawn on all difficulties, and there's no difference between them, so you're best off blitzing through it on Normal. Your character will comment on the mushroom patch when you're in the room with it.

Comment: Also something to note, the mushrooms will typically spawn in rooms without enemies. I've yet to see them spawn in a populated room, which seems to be the general consensus.

Comment: @Chris: Is Adria's Hut (overground) also a spawn point? I seem to remember getting mine there, but it was so long ago that all these posts about Cathedral lvl 1 make me uncertain :(

Comment: I don't believe Adria's Hut is a spawn point, however I haven't seen any testimony for/against the idea. I wouldn't imagine it's a spawn point since it's pretty far from Cathedral Level 1 but there may have been changes to the spawn point locations since I first looked into this (unlikely but possible).

Answer (score 2):

The room that holds the black mushrooms is as described by the other answerers, but your character does not (or perhaps "no longer") comments on them upon entering the room. As of June 1, 2012 at least, your character will comment on the mushrooms only after you've "looted" the patch, or at least walked nearly on top of it.

Also, I personally found my mushrooms in a room that was absolutely swarming with enemies, so the observation that they are mostly in rooms without enemies is probably true, but not without exceptions.

(I was not allowed to comment upon the answers or comments in question, so I am forced to submit an "answer" of my own.)

Comment: You will be allowed to comment at 50 rep.

Comment: +1 for useful info on character commenting to help you ;). Staff of Herding was a bit obvious imho so can't give rep for that.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Mushroom) the black Mushroom is customarily found on Cathedral Level 1, but it is *very* rare. You may need to reset the dungeon quite a few times before stumbling upon it. Your best bet would defintley be to clear out every inch of Level 1 then reset the dungeon until you come across it.

Answer (score 0):

It only spawns in the room with two entrances perpendicular to each other. If you do not see this room, then reset the level and try again.