# Sharing Whimsyshire crafting materials between difficulties

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got Black Mushrooms in our nightmare run of D3, and I got Leoric's bone from the Normal difficulty. Can I combine these materials (plus the rest of course) to build the staff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only restrictions are these:

- The materials are **account bound** so they cannot be traded or sold on the auction house
- The materials can only be used to craft the Staff of Herding for **Normal** difficulty.  Crafting the higher grade staves requires that you have the Staff of Herding from the previous difficulty + the plans for the upgraded variant, which can be bought during Act 4 of the difficulty in question.

With this in mind, you should be fine crafting the staff with ingredients taken from multiple characters or difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to combine pieces from different difficulties for the recipe.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you believe I should add to make it complete?