# Does magic find affect areas?

Tags: diablo-iii

At some point, Diablo 3 generates a map which may or may not have various random figures/events/dungeons.  Does the Magic Find skill have anything to do with this?  Specifically I'm wondering in regards to finding various parts of the Whimsyshire staff - should I load up on magic find gear before I go looking for things like black mushrooms and the mysterious cave?

Comment: Very, very similar to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/69021/13845

Comment: True, but he asked it after me :)

Comment: nope, you're a day after him :)  That question was asked on 5/22, this on 5/23.

Answer (score 1):

No, magic find has nothing to do with map generation.

Answer (score 1):

No, Magic Find % multiplies the drop rate on the item its self. If an item has a .0005% chance to drop, and you have 100% MF then the item now has a .0010% chance to drop. So you may find it harder to get items, but it's not because the map or difficulty, Just plain old chance. An item always has a potential to drop.