# What does it mean 'there is no cow level'?

Tags: diablo-iii

In a loading screen it said that there is no cow level. What is this referring to?

Comment: Found a screen cap of the message linked [elsewhere](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-whimsyshire-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii): http://i.stack.imgur.com/HwilC.jpg

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Way back with Diablo 1, there were rumors that clicking repeatedly on the corpse of a specific cow would open up a secret level.

Blizzard denied this (rightfully so), and made a humorous nod to the rumor by including a cheat code in their game Starcraft.  Typing "there is no cow level" into the console would allow you to skip a level.

In Diablo 2, they added an actual secret cow level.

In Diablo 3, they did not add in a cow level, but instead added a different [secret level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-whimsyshire-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Starcraft reference.  I actually initially thought this question was in reference to the old Broodwar.  Kudos to you sir either way :)

Comment: I'm so glad you mentioned the Starcraft reference.  Pretty much Fredley, it's an ongoing Blizzard joke through their games.

Comment: the joke was repeated in WoW's loading screens early on, responded by community that Thunderbluff is one

Answer (score 8):

If you know nothing else about video games, know these three things:

1. **The cake is a lie.**
2. **There is no cow level.**
3. **All your base are belong to us.**

With this knowledge, no video game meme will ever confuse you.

Comment: You definitely forgot the arrow to the knee meme, though everyone hates that now :D

Comment: I probably blocked it out because of that time when i was younger that I wanted to be an adventurer, but then I took an arrow to the knee =P

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question. It should be a comment.

Comment: @The Jug - I acknowledge that. There was already a great answer to the question, I figure the humor could be appreciated.

Comment: -1 I agree with @TheJug

Answer (score 2):

Its referring to Diablo 2. There was a Secret Level the "Cow Level". Blizzard said in Diablo 3 will be no Cow Level.

But... in D3 are Secret Levels.