# Is there any achievement related to Whimsyshire?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

To get to the Happy Rainbow Unicorn Candy Land we have to go through the time-consuming and expensive construction of the Staff of Herding.

Is there any in-game recognition of our effort, in form of an Achievement or Feat of Strength, or our only reward is getting to that creepy place infested with the Virus of Happiness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a feat of strength for entering Whimsyshire - [In the Land of Killer Unicorns](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/in-the-land-of-killer-unicorns) - and it even unlocks a [banner pattern](http://d3db.com/static/gameasset/textures/banner_basic_pattern_star_01.png) and [sigil](http://d3db.com/static/gameasset/textures/banner_basic_sigilMain_unicorn_01.png) for you.