# what does the "black mushroom" good for in the full version of D3

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “Black Mushroom” item used for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63563/what-is-the-black-mushroom-item-used-for)

In the question [What is the "Black Mushroom" item used for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63563/what-is-the-black-mushroom-item-used-for), an answer was given for the beta. I want to know the same, for the full version. Is the black mushroom just an Easter-egg, or does it has a role in the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's used for the creation of the staff of herding](http://d3db.com/item/i/plan-staff-of-herding), which is needed to open [the secret level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii).