# How do I get rid of extra Black Mushrooms?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was told to submit this as a question... I've been trying to get rid of my Four Black mushrooms in my stash but I have no clue how to... any help is welcome...I have tried Salvaging them, but can't. I have also attempted to sell them, but that doesn't work. I've tried asking for help on the general chat, but was only told what they were used for. I tried posting it in a Diablo 3 forum, but have not gotten a response... I don't know where I'm supposed to get the other items to create the staff. I have a Diablo 3 game... please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "Black Mushroom" item used for?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63563/what-is-the-black-mushroom-item-used-for)

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Do you want to get rid of the Black Mushroom? Or do you want to use it to make a Staff of Herding? The latter is certainly a duplicate, the former isn't.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect what the post seems to be asking. Losse, if I am mistaken, feel free to edit it back.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways to get rid of the extra *Black Mushrooms*:

1. Toss it(throw in on the ground) and forget it
2. Create a new hero, give all the unwanted items to him, then delete this hero

Comment: This is my go-to way of getting rid of account-bound items that can't be sold to the merchants.  Put them on a new character and delete the character.  +1

Comment: Option 2 seems like a really long winded way of getting things. What advantages does this have over just tossing the loot? Oh, or can you not drop account bound items on the ground?

Comment: no you can absolutely drop account bound items.

Comment: @Chris depends on the items. Some items can't be dropped on the ground(for example *Diablo 3 CE* Wings and Dyes, Staff of Herding iIrc and some others)

Answer (score 2):

If an item is unsellable and unsalvageable then you can throw it away. You can do this as simply as dragging it from your inventory to the main screen to drop it on the floor and then ignoring it until it goes away. I would assume it will be lost when you reload your game but it may be that progressing through quests or other things will also cause dropped items to disappear - I'm not really sure on that but it will be guaranteed gone by the next time you play the game. :)

Comment: Leaving the game and starting a new one will definitely remove items on the ground (assuming you don't reenter the same game if some other player stayed in it of course).  Items will also stay on the ground for a certain period of time based on the 'quality' (grey, white, blue, etc) with higher quality items taking longer to despawn.

Answer (score 0):

With the Black Mushroom you can create the Staff of Herding.

List of requirements for the staff and its upgrades:

Staff of Herding: Requires

- Black Mushroom
- Wirt’s Bell
- Liquid Rainbow
- Gibbering Gemstone
- Leoric’s Shinbone
- a 50,000 gold crafting cost

Nightmarish Staff of Herding: Requires the Staff of Herding and a 200,000 gold crafting cost

Hellish Staff of Herding: Requires the Nightmarish Staff of Herding and a 500,000 gold crafting cost

Infernal Staff of Herding: Requires the Hellish Staff of Herding and a 1,000,000 gold crafting cost

The total cost to craft the final version, the Infernal Staff of Herding, is 1,750,000 gold.

It has also been confirmed that the staff is used to get to the secret level.

Here is a [link](http://www.diablowiki.net/Staff_of_Herding) with a list where all the items can be found.

Comment: This is completely outdated. You can't craft "Nightmarish Staaf of Herding" or the others anymore, since these difficulties are removed. The "Staff of herding" ittself is now the final version.

Answer (score 0):

Black Mushroom is part of the ingredient to create Staff of Herding, you only require 1 so you can just throw the extra away. The staff is use to unlock a secret dungeon in Act 1 called [Whimsyshire](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Whimsyshire).

Ingredients to create the staff are as follow:

- Black Mushroom - Found rarely in a room on Cathedral level one, in early Act One.
- Leoric's Shinbone - Found rarely in the fireplace in Leoric's Manor, in late Act One.
- Wirt's Bell - An Act II vendor (Squirt) sells it for 100,000 gold on her Potions and Dyes tab.
- Liquid Rainbow - Spawns in the Mysterious Cave in the Mysterious Chest in the Oasis, Act 2.
- Gibbering Gemstone - Random drop from Chiltara in the Caverns of Frost, Level 2, Act 3.
- Plan: Staff of Herding - To teach the recipe to Haedrig. Drops randomly from Izual, Act 4.

More detail on how to acquire ingredients are [here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Staff_of_Herding).

On previous version you are able to upgrade the staff to use in different difficulty, however with current update is not necessary anymore nor can you upgrade it.